# Dji Bridge App?

Tags: java, android, debugging, sdk, dji-sdk

Hi I am developing an Dji Android app now, and need to track some variable and functions while running the app, and found this [beta version Android Bridge App (with limited usage instruction)](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Android-Bridge-App), also found the [Dji SDK](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/SDKManager/DJISDKManager.html#djisdkmanager_enterdebugmode_inline) information about that here, but it doesn't give any example.

I tried to put the following code in my MainActivity.java file, but it doesn't run.

```
public void enableBridgeModeWithBridgeAppIP(String bridgeAppIP){
    MainActivity.this.enableBridgeModeWithBridgeAppIP("192.168.178.115");
    Log.v(TAG, "BridgeMode is on");

}
```

can any one help me understand how to add/change code in your app to make it run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bridge app current sole purpose is to expose to a wireless interface (through websockets) the connection to the product which happens in USB through AoA.

The way you use it is to connect a device to the remote controller in USB, launch the app and use the ip given in the interface.

From then on, you can develop your app from your computer or device connected to your computer - which gives you access to all debugging tools.

Once you have this setup running you can add tracking code inside your app rather than in the bridge.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, but how exactly can I implement this, what code do I need to put into which file? the document says I need to pass the "enableBridgeModeWithBridgeAppIP" the IP address shown on the bridge app.

Comment: That's pretty much all you need. Call the enableBridgeModeWithBridgeAppIP from DJISDKManager and you're done.